# Android Searchview with autocomplete style

Tags: android, user-interface, autocomplete, autocompletetextview, searchview

What's the best approach in Android to get a searchview with autosearch results styled like this example from the Uber app? I especially like how the results are displayed directly on the screen and not with a dropdown look.

[image: Uber Search page]

I was thinking possibly getting the query of a search and add the results on the screen dynamically as buttons but there must be a simple way to achieve the style and functionality they have here. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: see `SearchView#setOnQueryTextListener(SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener)` here in your listener you can call your `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)`

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at the Android's Uber app, and there they have an `EditText` on the top with a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) below that. Whenever the user types in anything in the `EditText`, the query is made to the server to get the data from it, and the results are displayed in the `ListView` below.

You should make the query to the server in [`afterTextChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) method of the `EditText` `TextWatcher`. Also, make sure when the user is typing in continuously, cancel the previous request and only the latest char change query string should go in the request.